# Remove list elements - my approach for best performance in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

If I need to remove elements in a list, will the following be better than using `LinkedList`:

```
int j = 0;
List list = new ArrayList(1000000);
...
// fill in the list code here
...
for (Iterator i = list.listIterator(); i.hasNext(); j++) {
    if (checkCondition) {
        i.remove();
        i = list.listIterator(j);
    }
}
```

?

`LinkedList` does "remove and add elements" more effectively than `ArrayList`, but `LinkedList` as a doubly-linked list needs more memory, since each element is wrapped as an `Entry` object. While I need a one-direction `List` interface, because I'm running over in ascending order of index.

Comment: You need to define "better" - is it speed or memory that matters most?

Comment: Definitely agreed with @DNA, also refine what the access pattern / add delete frequency is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: it depends on the frequency and distribution of your add and removes.  If you have to do only a *single* remove infrequently, then you might use a linked list.  However, the *main* killer for an `ArrayList` over a `LinkedList` is constant time random access.  You can't really do this with a normal linked list (however, look at a skip list for some inspiration..).  Instead, if you're removing elements *relative* to other elements (where, you need to remove the next element) then you should use a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple answer to this:

- It depends on what you are optimizing for.  Do you care **more** about the time taken to perform the operations, or the space used by the lists?
- It depends on how long the lists are.
- It depends on the proportion of elements that you are removing from the lists.
- It depends on the other things that you do to the list.

The chances are that one or more of these determining factors is not predictable up-front; i.e. you don't really know.  So my advice would be to put this off for now; i.e. just pick one or the other based on gut feeling (or a coin toss).  You can revisit the decision  later, if you have a quantifiable performance problem in this area ... as demonstrated by cpu or memory usage profiling.